# TFS 2010 TF30065 An unhandled exception occurred

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have Install new instance of sql server in the server and Now the TFS2010 not working with error :

> TF30065 An unhandled exception occurred

I can't found the real error to fix it, how I know the error detail or how I fix this ! there's many project in it and I have to fix it

edit: I found the error log of the error

> Message d'exception : Échec du chargement du fichier Msxmlsql.dll.
>   L'instruction préparée avec le handle 0 est introuvable.
>   sp_xml_removedocument : la valeur fournie pour le paramètre numéro 1
>   n'est pas valide.
>   WIN-Server\SQLEXPRESS.Tfs_Configuration..prc_QueryCatalogNodes:
>   Database Statement Failure - Error %error="8179";% executing INSERT
>   statement for @pathSpec L'instruction a été arrêtée. (type
>   SqlException)

Comment: Duplicate question: http://serverfault.com/questions/434383/tfs-2010-tf30065-an-unhandled-exception-occurred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have remove the second sql instance but the same error, then I have upgrade the first instnace from 10.0 to 10.50 the same of the new instance installed and it work now